# absolute positioning within relative list item elements in ie6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, css-position

This is driving me mad:

```
<ul>  
   <li style="position:relative;border:1px solid green">  
      <p>some content...</p>  
      <p>some content...</p>  
      <a style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:red; display:block">a mask over whole list item</a>  
   </li>  
</ul>
```

ive encountered this problem in various guises (e.g. positioning corner graphics, trying to create a mask over a list item etc)

no matter what i try, i cant get ie6 to absolutely position elements within a list item. another example:

```
<ul>  
   <li style="position:relative;border:1px solid green">  
      <p>some content...</p>  
      <p>some content...</p>  
      <div style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:20px; height:20px; background:red; display:block"></div>  
      <div style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0; width:20px; height:20px; background:green; display:block"></div>  
      <div style="position:absolute; left:0; bottom:0; width:20px; height:20px; background:blue; display:block"></div>  
      <div style="position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0; width:20px; height:20px; background:yellow; display:block"></div>  
   </li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: are you running in quirks mode? what is your doctype?

Comment: Hi MP, FYI you can use CTRL-K to indent whole code blocks and preserve formatting - or manually indent code at least 4 spaces and it will be handled correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It worked with IE6  when I added the property

```
zoom: 1;
```

to the ul element. I don't know why this works.